# How do I display the result in real time when I type the numbers in the fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, numbers

Can be in pure JS, JQuery, JS...
I just need you to use the same logic below:

```
Exemple:
<input type="number">
<input type="number">
<input type="number">
<input type="number">

<label for="total">Total:</label>
<input class="total" id="total" type="number" name="test">

<script type="text/javascript">
let total = 0;
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]').forEach(el=>total+=+el.value);
document.querySelector('#total').value = total;
console.log(total);
</script>
```

Comment: You can do this with just HTML actually. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/output

Comment: @JSilv Using inline event handlers is bad practice and results in poorly factored, hard-to-manage code. Put your Javascript in your .js, not in your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just don't have function to run your code on change or on keypress etc... 
you need to make the calculation when one number change or when key pressed on document

```
<input type="number">
<input type="number">
<input type="number">
<input type="number">

<label for="total">Total:</label>
<input class="total" id="total" type="number" name="test">

<script type="text/javascript">
 function  keyDownTextField(){
let total = 0;
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]').forEach(el=>total+=+el.value);
document.querySelector('#total').value = total;
console.log(total);
  }

  document.addEventListener("keyup", keyDownTextField, false);



</script>
```

https://codepen.io/jehadja/pen/gexddJ -- working example

Comment: Perfect!! Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

```js
const inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]')].slice(0, 4);

function getTotal() {
  const total = inputs
    .reduce((totalSoFar, el) =>
      el.value ? totalSoFar + Number(el.value) : totalSoFar
    , 0);
  document.querySelector('#total').value = total;
  console.log(total);
}
inputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('change', getTotal));
```

```html
<input type="number">
<input type="number">
<input type="number">
<input type="number">

<label for="total">Total:</label>
<input class="total" id="total" type="number" name="test">
```